# Editing CharacterSpacing annotation attribute in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation

I want to change the character spacing for a single (selected) feature/record in a file geodatabase annotation feature class.

I understand that the CharacterSpacing attribute controls that, but changing the default (0) to other values (positive or negative) does nothing. By comparison, editing CharacterWidth does work as expected.

Any ideas?

I am running ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 Advanced on Windows 10.

Comment: Could you have a rule (from Maplex, but stored now in your annotation) that limits overflow of text? I have never seen what you describe.

Comment: I do not. And I tested CharacterSpacing with both positive and negative values. Neither worked. If limiting the overflow of text were the reason, shrinking the text with negative character spacing should have worked. It did not.

Answer (score 1):

CharacterSpacing *does* work as expected on pieces of annotation that have not been edited previously. Once you edit a piece of annotation ArcMap places a lock on it that prevents you from (some but not all types of) future edits.

So *perhaps* the solution to this problem is to reorder the sequence and types of annotation edits and see what works and what does not by trial and error.

Personally, I will implement the more practical solution of avoiding editing annotation attributes altogether.